# sometimes nanosleep sleeps too long time: not microsec unit, but second unit

Tags: scheduled-tasks, mips, embedded-linux

I am an embedded software engineer and now works with a MIPS device.
A thread with RR-scheduled is looping infinitely to execute a job and sleep 1 second. I used nanosleep function to sleep 1 second.
However, sometimes it does not wake until 13~4 seconds, not 1 second.  I know that nanosleep does not support the exactly sleeping time in the case of the nanosecond value, but it is very odd that the second value differs a lot.

The thread is RR scheduled, and the system runs 10 applications in the embedded linux environment.  Quite many threads are executing with RR schedules. I wonder it may bring the current bug.

Do you have any experience about the time bug in nanosleep, not nanosecond but second value?

Comment: Some other thread(s) in the system are preventing the thread that is sleeping for 1 second from running after the sleep is finished.

Comment: @markgz Would you explain more about the threads that can prevent the sleeping?  Is it related with the task scheduling?

Comment: I checked the CPU usage during the test and tried to find some processes and tasks that took too much CPU, but it did not help me.  Do you have an idea about finding the threads you mentioned?